# Digital microphone : I2S data output

Tags: microphone, digital

I have been playing around with some digital microphones, which have an I2S interface. I managed to get it working (Arduino board with small I2S mems board). At least, I think I did.

When reading the I2S specification, or the microphone datasheet, I can not seem to find the answer to the following simple questions;
1. What do the digital values represent?
2. How do you convert the digital values to dbFS (and then later an dbSPL)?

The SPH0645LM4H-B (Knowles) microphone seems to output all negative values (?). I read somewhere you have to "subtract the midpoint" to eliminate the large DC offset?!
On the other hand, a support engineer at Invensense explained to me that the ICS-43434 outputs positive and negative values which "represent the amplitude of the signal relative to +/-full scale".

I expected I2S to be a standard; isn't that the case ... ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's about interpreting a datasheet (not even provided), not programming in the SO sense.

Comment: It is not even clear it's not a hardware issue. Oh, and: did you find any ISO/IEEE/etc. standard for I2S? (hint: you won't, as it is not a standard. A norm at best)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), *perhaps* [electronics.se]. However, be sure to *read the site's on-topic page prior to posting*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save each sample of the digitized data, this word of 24 bits when converted to decimal, will give you a voltage. This voltage is what you need to calculate RMS value, and later on calculate your db SPL.

Which arduino board are you using to make it work? most arduino doesn't have I2S communication, I think Arduiino Zero and MKR are the ones available for the taks. You would achieve a better perfomance if you use STM32 microcontrollers, which have floating point, 32 bits processor, DMA.. etc.

Comment: For each sample the ICS43434 returns a 3-byte int32 (positive or negative) in a 4 byte int32 data type. That extra byte can be anything so you have to ignore it. The thing is you have to ignore it in such a way that you don't mess up the intent of the two's compliment value when you legitimize the high byte.. You have to look at the highest of the 24 bits. You have to copy the value of that bit into all the bits in the high byte. Eg sample = ((sample & 0x800000) == 0)? sample &= 0x00FFFFFF : sample |= 0xFF000000; What's it mean? It is a number point between +/-8,388,607 in the sound wave form.

Comment: The I2S protocol can be MSBit or LSBit first. In the case of MSBit first, the last 8 bits of the 32-bit sample are either going to be 0 or garbage. In both cases you should be able to right-shift the sample value and the MSBit value will be maintained by the shift operation. In the case of LSBit first you would have to throw away the top 8 bits, and that's where you would need to figure out the value of the MSBit of _data_ and ensure that the top bits are set or cleared correctly.